# Is there a way to create a reverse viewshed with ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, viewshed

I am working on an environmental assessment. A data request has been made which it seems is kind of like a reverse viewshed, in that they want a layer that displays all locations within the raster that can view a single high point.

I have the appropriate raster and point layers, but if I run the Viewshed tool as is, pretty much the entire output is returned as not visible. Any thoughts on a workflow to try to capture what they are looking for? The only thing I've come up with so far is to use a bunch of random points surrounding the high point within the raster and include them in a viewshed, but this would not be a complete analysis of the area.

In this scenario, every cell in the raster would be a potential observer. I'll need the output to display values for those cells that can view the high point (1) versus those cells that cannot (0).

I tried running the standard viewshed tool, using the high point as the observer, along with the hillshade as the raster. The output returned the entire area as (0) with only a few cells directly around the high point as (1).

Comment: You are correct in using the viewshed tool.  You mention both a single high point and then an area.  Which do you need? The viewshed and viewshed tools will take multiple points (or lines) as inputs.  If you have an area on top of the hill to consider then there are several ways to create those data.  The hillshade tools will take lines and multiple points as inputs.

Comment: What parameters have you used as far as ObserverA and B are concerned?

Comment: If you run the Viewshed tool on the high point, it will return all the areas that are visible from the high point. Doesn't that by default also mean that the high point is visible from those areas?

Comment: In this scenario, every cell in the raster would be a potential observer. I'll need the output to display values for those cells that can view the high point (1) versus those cells that cannot (0).

Comment: I tried running the standard viewshed tool, using the high point as the observer, along with the hillshade as the raster. The output returned the entire area as (0) with only a few cells directly around the high point as (1)

Comment: Hillshade? Don't you want to use a DEM as the raster?

If you've been using hillshade, there's your problem. You need surface elevation data as your raster. Hillshade is just nothing more than pretty shadows cast by the sun.

Comment: You probably want to add a slight offset to the high point (2 m) as if you were standing at that point looking out.

Comment: J.W.: Thanks, yep I figured out that I needed to use the DEM. It gave better results but was still blocking out huge areas that should have been visible.

Comment: Matthew- yes. It looks like the high point was actually mis-placed, and wasn't situated at the actual highest point along the ridge. I will re-run with an offset and see how that goes. Thanks!